# Is there any platform to read the Mempool?

Tags: blockchain

I want to see the queued transactions in the mempool, where can I see that?
Thank you.

Comment: Is there any Update on that issue as of today? So is there any chance to read (historic) cardano mempool transactions?

Comment: Please see this API: https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Mempool
Also note that a mempool is a local viewpoint, and other nodes might have a different mempool at the same time. It's a local measurement of an individual node.

Answer (score 3):

Cardano doesn't have a ***mempool*** in traditional sense, due to the fact that you have only 20 second interval between previous block and a current one. It is rather a kind of stack that stores an average of 60-90 transactions. And someone hardly needs an API that reads a 20 second stack.

Comment: But I'd like to add that it is possible. Open whatever process you need as a child of a process you are in control of. You'll now have access to the memory buffers. It will take forever to figure out what is what and is deffs hacking but can be done if the need is truly strong enough

Answer (score 0):

A protocol to interface with the local mempool [was merged recently](https://github.com/input-output-hk/ouroboros-network/pull/3404) in the context of a [larger piece of work to increase network throughput](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/issues/3247). It can now be accessed from [Ogmios](https://ogmios.dev/mini-protocols/local-tx-monitor/).

Even though, unfortunately it does not provide access to transactions received from peers - only to those submitted locally.

Comment: You should follow the [referencing](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) guidelines when referring to external sources.  Your answer may not work well if the external sources move or change.