# Cardano mempool

Tags: transaction, mempool

I have looked at this thread: [Is there any platform to read the Mempool?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/3995/is-there-any-platform-to-read-the-mempool/9467#9467) asking if there is a way to read the (historic) cardano mempool. Back then, there was none so I was wondering if anything has changed since then. Anyone familiar with a method/ webpage that reports historic cardano mempool transactions?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "historic" mempool. The mempool is ephemeral. It is updated every time a new block arrives.

It is however possibly to reconstruct the mempool for any point in time using something like `cardano-db-sync` or by replaying all blocks up to a certain point in time and applying them to the ledger.